# How to block screenshot when my app is active in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, screenshot

**NETFLIX** app prevents screen shots and screen recording over its app in IOS devices. How to implement this feature in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iOS 11 you can use *UIScreen* to detect when the screen is being captured. For more info follow the official documentation: [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1970/_index.html).

Comment: It detect after the screenshot has been taken, not before I think. So it's not preventing.

Comment: There is actually no way to stop the user from capturing the screen, however you can manage what he can capture. As Apple states: "For example, if you are a media application you would observe changes to UIScreen.isCaptured and if its value is true you could stop playback and present a useful dialog to the user letting them know that playback was paused due to being captured".